# Execution sequence for OpenGL commands

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo, render-to-texture

I have a program where I use a shader program to render to a texture attached to a FBO then change the parameters of the program (by changing the values of the uniforms) and render to a second texture after attaching it to the FBO. The two rendered images are then used to generate a third one.

I'm not sure if the results I'm getting is correct. I understand that the GPU will be free to choose the time at which to execute an OpenGL command. But that should not be a problem so long as the order of execution does follow the sequence in which the commands appear in the code. Is this actually the case?

A follow-up question. I need to save the generated frames to disk. I know how to that. But I need to make sure that the GPU has completed the rendering before doing so. How can I enforce that?

Comment: This will work, provided you never try to sample from the same texture you are drawing into (that will create feedback loops). And generally what you are describing is not a problem, some newer stuff that was introduced to GL4 like image load/store throws a lot of this stuff on its head, but you should pretend I never mentioned that and avoid panicking over a falling sky :)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks Ando. That's exactly what I'm not so sure about. The steps I'm following are the ones I mention in the comment on user1781290's answer. I use one shader program when drawing to the first two textures, and a second shader program to draw to the third texture. At all times, there is only one FBO. I only change the attached texture at each stage. I also tried adding `glFinish()` but I still have this mismatch problem I mention in my second comment on user1781290's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL will execute the commands in the order they're issued (or at least simulate this behavior). This means, that there is no problem with using 2 different FBOs, one after another. Also this means OpenGL will make sure, that your rendering is complete at the time you get your result from the FBO.

You can call `glFinish()` to have your program wait until all pending OpenGL commands have been processed by the pipeline, but this is unnecessary in almost all cases.

Comment: I do no use 2 FBOs. But I attach one texture to the FBO, call glDraw to render to that texture, attach another texture, and call glDraw again to render to the second texture. I then attach a third texture to the FBO and render the final outcome to it using samples from the two previous textures. Would that sequence work?

Comment: The reason I believe something is wrong is that the frames that I'm generating are from input video frames. I read the frames into frame buffers then do the processing on the buffered frames one by one. But when I look at the output frames that I save, there seems to be a mismatch (i.e., frame 300 in the output does not correspond to frame 300 in the input, but rather is a few frames after it).

Comment: Thanks. Accepting the answer. It turned out to be a bug in the code I have for buffering the decoded frames.